# Issue with UIActivityIndicatorView showing up in screen shot

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

So I have a page with a tableview full of names that I want to take a screen shot of and print with airprint.  Unfortunately if I try and add that cool little activity indicator spinner guy, he shows up in the screenshot!  very unacceptable.  But the whole point is to have him spinning while the app is busy taking the screenshot.  (sometimes multiple shots because of multiple pages and takes ten seconds or so)  any thoughts?? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are taking the screenshot...if you're using renderInContext, just test to make sure the current view isn't the activityIndicator before drawing (so the spinning thing won't be drawn).

Comment: I am using renderInContext:     
[[((UIScrollView *)self.view) layer] renderInContext:context];

and the activityIndicator is a subview of self.view and it has no superview :(

Comment: And you can't change that hierarchy? Put everything you want in the screenshot in a "screenshot" container.